# Linked in verification issue when login to app

Tags: debugging, oauth, linkedin-api

I have an app which allows users to sign in with LinkedIn thought OAuth. We are having a problem with login authentication. It has been successfully worked last days but now they're asking to do the following step:

[image: Example]

But there is no space to enter the verification code. I think it is an update of LinkedIn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>LinkedIn Login Integration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
      api_key: "81xxxxxxxx"
      authorize: false
      onLoad:  onLinkedInLoad
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, 'auth', handleOnLoad)
      }

      function handleOnLoad(obj) {
        console.log('authorized success')
      }

      function authenticateUser() {
        IN.User.authorize(callbackFunction)
      }

      function callbackFunction() {
        console.log('callbackFunction fired')
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>LinkedIn</h1>
    <input type="button" value="authenticate" onclick="authenticateUser()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? Perhaps snippets of code, links to documentation, or any error messages you're getting.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I don't even know which app it's referring to since I'm using LI on like 15 tabs on Chrome on my laptop and I have the app installed on multiple devices...

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413779/please-enter-the-following-verifier-on-the-app-linkedin-social-login