# why linkedin social login not working showing 'Please enter the following verifier on the app '

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement LinkedIn social login using JavaScript and i am getting LinkedIn Login page.after submitting login Id and password it's showing some verification message **Please enter the following verifier on the app:
15217**

[image: please find verification message image]

Comment: Dupe of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293699/linked-in-verification-issue-when-login-to-app

Answer (score 1):

You are using V1 version of linkedin APIs. Please migrate your apis to V2. Linkedin javascript SDK is deprecated. Read migration guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context)