# "Please enter the following verifier on the app" LinkedIn social login

Tags: angular-social-login

I am implementing social login in angular 6 app with Linkedin using this npm package 
https://github.com/NarHakobyan/ngx-linkedIn

After clicking on allow popup in the Linkedin login page it redirects me to a page where the below text is written

**Please enter the following verifier on the app:
*****.**

I searched and found many peoples are facing this issue. Can you please tell how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V1.0 of linkedin apis. They have [migrated](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates) apis to V2.0. Use V2.0 ( [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow) ) and you won't get this error.

Sample Get  request

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.yoursite.com/oauth2/callback&state=fooobar&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social

Comment: Yeah, I realised that. I successfully implemented the Linkedin APIs. But till May 1 we can only get light profile i.e only name and country. I wasn't able to identify any unique key by which I can uniquely identify users. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: v2 APIs will return only light profile. For fetching more information , need to apply LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program . Please see migration guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context